# solution for combining two text files missing different headers

Tags: windows, shell, sed, awk, grep

I am running in a windows environment and have not used grep/awk/sed/shell; however, I would like to know what would be the simplest solution for the following issue:

I have two files (they both have headers):

1. Genetics File. The columns are Animal, Car, Color
2. Specimen File. The columns are Animal, Color

I would like to combine the two file into one file with all headers present; however, for the specimen file portion to have blank values for `Car`. The end product would be:

```
+----------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Animal  | Car  | Color |                                                                     |
+----------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Elephant | Jeep | Grey  | (from genetics file [don’t include this text in the resulting file) |
| Dog      | Ford | Red   | (from genetics file)                                                |
| Cat      |      | Blue  | (from specimen file)                                                |
| Donkey   |      | Green | (from specimen file)                                                |
+----------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What would be the simplest solution in a windows environment?

**edit**: to clarify the reason for those tags is because i believe that those tools are the best suited for this job! I do not want to create a whole c# application just to do this.

Comment: Why did you tag this with grep/awk/sed/shell in a windows environment?   Do you want to learn to use those under Windows?

Comment: @HenkLangeveld thank you for the question. because to me those seem to be the best tools for this job. am i not right?

Comment: @HenkLangeveld can you suggest to me a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The tools referred to in the question, `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc., are not native to Windows.

In order to use those them, you will have to make a choice:

- Install a unix or linux on your computer, either native, or through virtualisation.

or:

- Install a toolkit like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [UWIN](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/uwin/)

There's a lot of documentation out there for these projects, but there's a lot to learn, if you're new.

An easy way to get started with virtualisation is to get Oracle's [Virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org), and a copy of ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
$cat input.ani
|Elephant|Jeep|Grey|
$ cat input.Specimen
| Cat | Blue  |
| Dog | White |
| Elephant | Red |
$ cat input.Specimen  | awk    '{print $1 $2 $3 "   " $3 $4 $5 $6  }' >> input.ani
$ cat input.ani
|Elephant|Jeep|Grey|
|Cat|   |Blue|
|Dog|   |White|
|Elephant|   |Red|
```

Comment: cool!! can you help me to get this going on windows? what i need to do this?

Comment: hmm... never scripted on Win. I presume you can use something like WSH or VBscript to just read Specimen File line by line, breaking each line by | and simply print to the end of Genetics File,  making space between variables red. it is extremely easy task, so probably some Win guru could pop-up here and give Win-native solution.

Comment: dont want to use poopy vbscript :) what is the language you are using in yoru answer?

Comment: this is regular unix console. you can simply throw two your  files to any unix machine and  use  my answer.

Comment: You should be able to use this without modification from `cmd.exe` provided you van find an `awk` port for Windows.

Comment: A version of `awk` which has been compiled for Windows and perhaps adapted to the specifics of this environment.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, for a *simple* solution, I would not recommend against the unix toolset, unless you really want to get learn the environment.

For a Windows system, you could just as well install a good scripting language like `python`,  `perl`, or `ruby`.

None of those is trivial, but they have good support, and they have decent installers for windows.

Yet another alternative would be PowerShell, which again, is based on the .Net runtime.